# LESS integration in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, web-essentials, dotless

As far as I understand there are different solutions to handle .less files in a ASP.Net MVC application, including:

- [dot-less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/)
- [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/)

So far I'm working in an environment where Web Essentials is already installed and automatically compiles my .less files to CSS.

But in the [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) article they mention dot-less for .less files management and bundling.

Which is the recommended solution? Does anyone have feedback on how to integrate .less in an ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like dot-less for debugging, you shouldn't have to build every time you make a CSS change to see it in the website. Then in production dotless will also compile and minify the CSS for you. You just need to change the link to your css file in your layouts.

Comment: Do you know if Web Essentials will play well with dotless if I have both installed?

Comment: I have both installed without any issues. Web Essentials is VS extension and dotless is a part of the website, so they don't conflict. Web Essentials makes it nicer to edit the less files too - syntax highlighting and all that.